# rails 5 - undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Tags: undefined, ruby-on-rails-5

The error I'm getting is happening on this line:

```
existing_user = User.find_by email: user[:email].strip
```

This is the complete block:

```
def create_account
        user = params[:user]

        existing_user = User.find_by email: user[:email].strip

        return email_already_taken if !existing_user.nil?

        user = User.create(:email => user[:email],
                            :password => user[:password],
                            :password_confirmation => user[:password])

      end
```

**Trace:**

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):
```

I checked the rails 5 documentation on:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by

The example shows:

```
Post.find_by name: 'Spartacus', rating: 4
```

How do I fix this error?

Comment: `params[:user]` is nil. You're not passing any user params.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev so the error is from the line above, not the find by?

Comment: The error is from the line with `find_by`, but from `find_by` itself. Its parameters fail to evaluate, so it doesn't get to be called.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Thanks sergio! I confirmed by hardcoding an email into the find by and then the error goes down to the user.create which means it was the params. I'm testing the api using an app called Postman. How can I test post requests in my local environment by passing the requests through URL?

Comment: You can see request params in the rails server log.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I know what the request params are but I'm not sure how to build the http url to act as if I'm calling the api to make sure I get the right result. Does that make sense?

Comment: In the console, you can use `curl` for example. It can do POST requests and also send request body with data (also headers, cookies and whatnot) That's what I do.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I'm sorry man but can you please show me an example? I really appreciate your help

Comment: something like this: `curl -X POST http://example.com/api/v1/whatever -d '{"foo": "bar"}'`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev It's still not recognizing my params. They are `'{"user[email]" : "emailhere@email.com", "user[password]" : "passwordhere"}'` is this incorrect for what the expect params are? Thanks

Comment: Ah yes, to parse json in request body, you need appropriate content-type. Try form-encoded params first: `-d "user[email]=emailhere@email.com&user[password]=passwordhere"`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I tried `'"user": { {"email" : "emailhere@email.com", "password" : "passwordhere"} }'` and now it says `ParamInvalid.. Must be a Hash`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127950/discussion-between-sergio-tulentsev-and-walker).